# SQL UNION two tabes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

I have two tables results to union:

```
table1:
name 
product

table2:
name
product
```

I can do

```
select * from table1 where product LIKE 'p%' limit 3
```

and also:

```
select * from table2 where product LIKE 'p%' limit 3
```

but when I union there results with:

```
(select * from table1 where product LIKE 'p%' limit 3)
UNION ALL
(select * from table2 where product LIKE 'p%' limit 3)
```

I get only the result from the first query. What is wrong?

Comment: Do all the tables have the same fields?

Comment: is the second select returning some rows?

Comment: Have you been able to identify a specific row in table2 that is not showing up that should or are you just looking at the total number of returned records and assuming they're not there?

Comment: If you are expecting data for both queries, try removing the limit 3 from the unions - do you then get all records?

Comment: try without the where condition as Juniad said probably no result for second table

Comment: all tables have the same rows and both tables return 3 rows each but not in combination

Answer (score 1):

There seems nothing wrong with the query. Also `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates so the best guess is that your second table does not have the data for the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: all tables have the same rows and both tables return 3 rows each but not in combination

Comment: @userWebMobile Can you remove the `LIMIT` from both the queries and try. I guess there is some problem in MySQL when you combine `UNION ALL` and `LIMIT`.

Comment: this is not an option I need the limit

Answer (score 1):

Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

"UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL."
it really works me:

SELECT column_name FROM table_name1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name FROM table_name2
.
hope, it will help you. :)

Comment: both table are identical in their structure